# Совместное использование JQuery и Prototype

Tags: jquery, prototype

Подскажите, что делать? На странице установлена jquery 1.5.2 и prototype 1.7.0.0 и они не соглашаются вместе работать. В интернете нашел вот такое решение:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> $j = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

Но оно не помогло. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery.noConflict(); // Запускаем функцию до jQuery(document).ready()

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // здесь $ будет действовать как алиас jQuery
});
// здесь $ будет доступен для других библиотек
```